# How to synchronize data from 2 databases in 2 different servers in MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I read a lot about replication to solve this problem. But the problem is that my team leader is not accepting that solution, since it doesn't suit the current system, is there any solution that uses c # .net to solve it ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: MySQL may register all data changes using timestamp columns values and/or triggers. MySQL event procedure may save changed data into outfile. External schedule (cron) may transfer this outfile to the remote server. Remote server may import the data from the file into the tables.

Comment: Also you may use FEDERATED engine (if compiled into and enabled) for direct attaching a table from the remote server and query this table like it is local.

Comment: Oh, writing your own replication feature rather than the ones tried and tested on MySQL for years is obviously the right engineering choice. But if there's a solution maybe explaining why it isn't applicable in the current system would help limit the guess work in the answers. Do you have some examples of data? Do you know how to resolve conflicts (two similar rows on either side where both are changed)?

Comment: @Akina Sorry, FEDERATED have been reviewed in the past, but ignored

Comment: @all My team leader was targetting a solution using c # .net instead of MySQL tools, although I believe it was not optimal and there will be many errors going on, but he did not accept.

Comment: *My team leader was targetting a solution using c # .net instead of MySQL tools* You MUST use either TS columns or triggers, no alternative. Of course you may use c# procedures instead of MySQL Event Scheduler and CRON if you're sure that you will solve this task by the better way...

Comment: @Akina TS is impossible because we cannot change the structure of a customer's tables (but adding a new table may be considered). About the using Triggers, is there any way trigger can notify that CRUD is successful for web server ?

Comment: *About the using Triggers, is there any way trigger can notify that CRUD is successful for web server ?* Trigger may notify nobody. It may only mark in some service table that the data altering action was successful, and store the data state of a row before and after changing in this service table. Then your c# app may poll this service table and send this data to remote server - by time or by the amount of data changes. And trigger will check data changes only, not data selection.

Comment: @Akina your solution could only check for changes to the data in the table, but the c# application won't get any notice of that change, except creating jobs to poll the table. But my app manages the Parking lot, we need an immediate notification when the data changes.

Comment: No problems... create your own custom user-defined function with this action and use it. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/8.0/en/adding-udf.html

Comment: @Akina hi, i'm back. I have read through the documentation you gave, then refer to this link
https://github.com/debugthings/mysql_udf_dotnet this, but i don't understand how a udf can return the result for c # application. I wonder if you have any other reference source or the demo code. Many thanks !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225499/discussion-between-quantn-and-akina).